# Python - Changing or appending a variable in an object

Tags: python, object, pass-by-reference

In the following code, I am appending targets to the Chunk_Obj variable "forprop_list". When I iterate through the for loop on line 111, the variable "forprop_list" seems to remember the values appended previously in that loop.
I feel this is a simple fix, but I have been unable to see it.

Does this have to do with assigning an object to a variable? What is causing the loop to continue appending instead of using the new empty "forprop_list"?

```
import os, pprint
import Data_Obj, ChunkObj


# Takes an index from the txt files for parameters. Takes a data index for the data input.
class Network:

    data_obj = None

    net_index = int
    data_index = int
    hparams = []

    # Both of the following use the same referenced object:
    # Holds all the chunk objects by POSITION
    nn_chunks_dict = {}
    # Holds all the chunk objects by LAYER
    nn_layers_dict = {}

    # Generates the neural network configuration and chunks required for the current network.
    def __init__(self, nn_index=1, data_index=1):

        self.net_index = nn_index
        self.data_index = data_index
        self.data_obj = Data_Obj.DataObj(data_index)

        # Reads from txt file.
        # Instantiates the chunks, adds those to the dictionaries.
        self.configure_from_txt()
        print("\n", "The ./NetConfigs txt file was successfully read to 'nn_coords_dict'. \n")

        # Iterates the layers in the nn_layers_dict.
        # Generates forward propagation dictionaries via prop_connect.
        # i = ex. layer1, layer2, layer3...
        print("nn_chunks_dict: ",self.nn_chunks_dict, "\n")
        print("nn_chunks dict keys", self.nn_chunks_dict.keys())
        for i in self.nn_chunks_dict:
            print("i", i)
            self.chunk_prop(i)

        print("\nThis network is initialized!")

    # Reads from the index txt file.
    # Instatiates each chunk from those parameters and adds to the dictionary.
    def configure_from_txt(self):
        param_txt = open(os.path.join('./NetConfigs/%s.txt' % self.net_index)).readlines()

        # Extracts hyperparameters.
        for i in param_txt[0].strip('\n').split(';'):
            self.hparams.append(i.split(','))

        # Removes the hyperparameters and '\n' for configuring the network.
        del param_txt[0:2]

        # Extracts the position of the chunk from the first 2
        # indexes of the attribs to a string list.
        for i in param_txt:
            attribs_targs = i.strip('\n').split(':')
            attribs = attribs_targs[0].split(',')
            position = [str(attribs[0]), str(attribs[1])]

            if len(attribs_targs) > 1:
                temp_targets = attribs_targs[1]
                temp_targets = temp_targets.split(';')
                targets = []

                for i in temp_targets:
                    targets.append(i)
            else:
                targets = None

            temp_config_dict = {"activation": attribs[2],
                                "num_layers": int(attribs[3]),
                                "width": int(attribs[4]),
                                "targets": targets,
                                "position": position}

            temp_obj = ChunkObj.ChunkObj(self, temp_config_dict)
            print("TEMP OBJECT KEY NAME:", temp_obj.key_name)

            # Assigns the current iterative chunk attributes(temp_config_dict) to the POSITION dictionary.
            self.nn_chunks_dict[temp_obj.key_name] = temp_obj

            # Assigns the chunk obj to a list of the layers.
            if ("layer%s" % position[0]) in self.nn_layers_dict:
                print("LAYER: layer%s" % position[0])
                self.nn_layers_dict["layer%s" % position[0]].append(temp_obj)

            else:
                self.nn_layers_dict["layer%s" % position[0]] = [temp_obj]
                print("LAYER: layer%s" % position[0])

        print("\n This networks configuration dictionary: \n")
        pprint.pprint(self.nn_chunks_dict)
        pprint.pprint(self.nn_layers_dict)

    def chunk_prop(self, chunk_name):
        x = self.nn_chunks_dict[chunk_name]
        # else, targets are the next layer chunks
        if x.targets is None:
            # self.placehold_obj.forprop_list = []
            print("\nchunk: ", x.key_name, "\nTargets are NOT specified")
            print("Sequential layer: ", str(int(x.position[0]) + 1))

            if x.backprop:
                backpropvar = True

            # if a next layer exists...
            next_layer = str(int(x.position[0]) + 1)
            if ("layer%s" % next_layer) in self.nn_layers_dict:
                for i in self.nn_layers_dict["layer%s" % next_layer]:
                    x.forprop_list.append(str(i.key_name))

                    # for later use:
                    """
                    if backpropvar:
                        i.backprop_list.append(self.placehold_obj.key_name)
                        print("Passed self to target backprop.")
                    """
            # else, the chunk is the last layer, forward prop will go to "y".
            else:
                # Checks to see if this chunk is in the last layer (will require Y for dimensions).
                print("Next layer does not exist. Last layer == True")
                x.last_layer = True
                x.forprop_list = ["y"]

        # if targets are specified...
        else:
            x.forprop_list = x.targets
            print("self.placeholder.key_name: ", x.key_name)
            print("Targets ARE specified: ", x.forprop_list)
            print("forprop list: ", x.forprop_list)


def test():
    Network()
    print("\n", "Network_Obj test complete!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a *minimal* example that reproduces your issue. Making us slog through over a hundred lines of your code is *not* conducive to getting an answer.

Comment: Aside from that, this seems to be a well posed question.

Comment: Guideline from the canned message that comes with the close vote I just cast: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"

Comment: We can't count till line 111 plus I can't find where you have initialized the forprop_list. Please shorten the code to make it easy for everyone to understand.